# defining variables as strings

Tags: php

I'm building a shopping cart and have a simple but perplexing problem.
I'm not good at javascript, so here it goes.

I'm trying to get the id of a record who's upc is equal to upc.

```
<input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="get_product_id(<?=$row['upc']?>)" />
```

The reason I'm not getting the id directly is i'll be getting the record based on a list of options that builds the upc.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: rtt is not defined 
onclick
```

However, if i pass any column of the records that is an int it moves on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String literals in JavaScript must be quoted. The value of `$row['upc']` presumably doesn't include quote characters, so it is being treated as an identifier (a variable in that context).

Comment: Ah, gotcha. So either define the variable as a string earlier or put some more quotes on it right?

Comment: You'll have to put quotes on it either way.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting in apostrophes surrounding the upc-value:

```
<?php
$upc = $row['upc'];
?>
<input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="get_product_id('<?=$upc;?>')" />
```

If you need to treat it as a number in javascript, then just use parseInt().

Comment: Thanks! thats what i did